# Using through a proxy server

Tags: solrnet

I am trying to use the solrnet library to connect to my solr instance through a proxy server and I am not having any luck. Does anyone know if this is possible and if so how?

**EDIT: I tried to do this using the  configuration option as specified by [Mauricio Scheffer](https://stackoverflow.com/users/21239/mauricio-scheffer) but ran into an error on try to build the project. After resolving the related issue regarding the project being stored on NAS, I have implemented Mauricio's IHttpWebRequestFactory solution and it works perfectly**

Cheers,

Ed

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can either:

- set [`<defaultProxy>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kd3cf2ex.aspx) in your config (which defines a *global* proxy), or
- implement `HttpWebAdapters.IHttpWebRequestFactory` (included in SolrNet) and make your implementation return a `IHttpWebRequest` with the `Proxy` property set to whatever your need, then register your `IHttpWebRequestFactory` implementation in your IoC container.

Comment: Unfortunately running in a console app and using the `<defaultProxy>` config entry causes it not to build and implementing an IHttpWebRequest is massive overkill for my needs.

Comment: @Ed Bishop: setting a configuration entry cannot possibly cause anything not to build, since configuration is not compiled. Implementing IHttpWebRequestFactory is trivial (20 LoC tops), see the default implementation: https://github.com/mausch/SolrNet/blob/master/HttpWebAdapters/Impl/HttpWebRequestFactory.cs

Comment: @Ed: if you get any errors when setting `<defaultProxy>` please post them.

Comment: This is the config when it builds:
'<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>
  <startup>
    <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.0"/>
  </startup>
</configuration>'

When I add this:
'<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>
  <startup>
    <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.0"/>
  </startup>
  <system.net>
    <defaultProxy>
      <proxy proxyaddress="MY-PROXY"/>
    </defaultProxy>
  </system.net>
</configuration>'  
It fails to build.  
I have found that it's due to the project being on a network drive, I'll post the answer.

Answer (score 0):

This is the configuration when it built:

`<?xml version="1.0"?>`

`<configuration>`

`<startup>`

`<supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.0"/>`

`</startup>`

`</configuration>`

When I added this:
`<?xml version="1.0"?>`

`<configuration>`

`<startup>`

`<supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.0"/>`

`</startup>`

`<system.net>`

`<defaultProxy>`

`<proxy proxyaddress="MY-PROXY"/>`

`</defaultProxy>`

`</system.net>`

`</configuration>`

It failed to build.

I have found that it's due to the project being stored on a network drive. Moving the project to the local machine fixed it, although I have since run caspol to allow me to run it from the network area.

Ed

Comment: The fact that you were developing on a network drive is completely orthogonal to my solution... it's like saying "I couldn't modify web.config because I don't have write permissions"

Comment: @Mauricio Whilst I did not state that my project was running from a network drive, this is not "orthogonal" to your solution. I had already attempted to use the <defaultProxy> as it is a standard .net configuration option. This solution was not possible in my case specifically due to the circumstances I was working under. I will try to be more detailed in future, however your answer of implementing IHttpWebRequestFactory is the one I am using, so I will mark yours as the accepted answer.